An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions, How to handle this error
I have been trying to set up a basic server for a project I have been learning about and tried the code given, on my system to then make updates. I have been stuck with flask for the longest time.
This time whenever I run the code for extracting an IP, I get this error

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

I have tried multiple things like checking firewall, changing network connection, resetting my TCP/IP stack, restarting the device and restarting the DB on MySQL.
I have also checked the ports but am unable to find port 5000 in the list that my system returned and tried even with the port nearest to 5000 which in my case was 5040.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from sql_connection import get_sql_connection
import mysql.connector
import json

import product_dao
import orders_dao
import uom_dao

app = Flask(__name__)

connection = get_sql_connection()

@app.route('/getUOM', methods=['GET'])
def get_uom():
    response = uom_dao.get_uoms(connection)
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route('/getProducts', methods=['GET'])
def get_products():
    response = product_dao.get_all_products(connection)
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route('/insertProduct', methods=['POST'])
def insert_product():
    request_payload = json.loads(request.form['data'])
    product_id = product_dao.insert_new_product(connection, request_payload)
    response = jsonify({
        'product_id': product_id
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route('/getAllOrders', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_orders():
    response = orders_dao.get_all_orders(connection)
    response = jsonify(response)
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route('/insertOrder', methods=['POST'])
def insert_order():
    request_payload = json.loads(request.form['data'])
    order_id = orders_dao.insert_order(connection, request_payload)
    response = jsonify({
        'order_id': order_id
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

@app.route('/deleteProduct', methods=['POST'])
def delete_product():
    return_id = product_dao.delete_product(connection, request.form['product_id'])
    response = jsonify({
        'product_id': return_id
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Python Flask Server For Grocery Store Management System")
    app.run(port=5040)

I understand that there can't be much of an issue with the code as it is a working one which I have checked back from the original source. I am using a windows 11 system and python 3.11.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.
